# Coloring nodes and edges in node-weighted graph

Tags: graphs, np-complete, weighted-graphs, colorings

I have a graph $G$ with $n$ nodes and $O(n)$ edges. Each of the nodes has a positive integral weight at least 2, such that sum of all weights is at most $O(n)$. We want to color the nodes and edges red or blue, where coloring a node of weight $C$ costs $C$ units, and coloring an edge costs 1 unit.

Constraints:

- Any edge between two blue nodes must be blue
- Any edge between two red nodes must be red

There are no constraints on edges between a red and a blue node.

Also given is we have exactly $R$ red and $B$ blue units of color, such that $R + B$ = sum of weights of nodes + edges. (Again, edges have weight 1.)

The problem is to determine whether the graph can be colored in a way that meets these constraints.  Is this problem NP-complete?  I suspect it is, but I am not sure which problem I can use to reduce this from.

Comment: If the sum could be n², you could reduce from [sqrt-clique](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/65014/reduce-sqrtn-clique-to-clique) by having weights n and let R be $kn+{k \choose 2}$.

Comment: This does not work though, since we could end up coloring edges even if they are not from the clique